# Отмена действий скрипта при перезагрузке

Tags: ubuntu

Здравствуйте, скажите пожалуйста, если я запущу вот такой скрипт (`power.sh`):

```
echo 5 > /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode #активирует laptop_modeecho min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policyecho min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host1/link_power_management_policyecho min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host2/link_power_management_policyecho min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host3/link_power_management_policyecho min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host4/link_power_management_policyecho min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host5/link_power_management_policyecho min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host6/link_power_management_policyecho powersave > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor  echo powersave > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governorecho powersave > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_governor  echo powersave > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_governorecho 1 > /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/sched-mc-power-savingsecho 90 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratioecho 1 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratioecho 60000 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecsecho powersave > /sys/module/pcie_aspm/parameters/policyecho 10 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

То после перезагрузки всё станет так, как было до применения этого скрипта? Т. е. отменит ли перезагрузка изменения, который произвёл этот скрипт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, кроме

`echo 1 > /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/sched-mc-power-savings`

Comment: скажите пожалуйста, возможна ли такая команда:    echo auto > /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/sched-mc-power-savings

Comment: Возможна, если существует каталог /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/